# Problem with Pandas dataframe.mean() and slice error

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, mean

I have 2 databases :

df1:

```
                 control_1   Average_return    
2019-09-07          True            0    
2019-06-06          True            0
2019-02-19          True            0
2019-01-17          True            0
2018-12-20          True            0
2018-11-27          True            0
2018-10-12          True            0
   ...              ...            ...
```

df2:

```
                  return
2010-01-01          NaN
2010-04-01     0.010920
2010-05-01    -0.004404
2010-06-01    -0.025209
2010-07-01    -0.023280
   ...            ...
```

My aim is to do the average mean between two date from `df2` if `control_1` is `True`.

```
for i in range(0,df1.row):                          #I go through my data df1 

    if (control_1.iloc[i]==True):                        #I check if control_1 is true

      date_1=df1.index[i]-pd.to_timedelta(6, unit='d')    # I remove 6 days from my date

      date_2=df1.index[i]-pd.to_timedelta(244, unit='d')  # I remove 244 days from my date

      df1.["Average_return"].iloc[i]=df2["return"].iloc[date_1:date_2].mean() 

# I want to make the mean of the return between my date-6 days and my date-244 days
```

Unfortunately it gives me this error :

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [2019-05-31] of <class 'datetime.date'>
```

Is someone able to help me :) ?

the csv file from df1 is :

Comment: (control_1.iloc[i]=True) check this  ;)

Comment: Should it be `control_1.iloc[i]==True` ? is it a typo or your code runs this way?

Comment: Thank you guys, it was a mistake when I copied the code. :) unfortunately the problem is still here

Comment: Can you provide a copied part of your input file + the line of code you use to read in or alternatively example data frame you also tried instead of an printed output for df1 and df2?

Comment: I understand. I will remove my question and rewrite it more clearly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58975665/problem-in-the-selection-of-a-part-of-data-in-pandas