# Problem in the selection of a part of data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, average

I have the following database that are extracted with pandas from csv files :

```
df1=pd.read_csv(path,parse_dates=True)
```

The print of df1 gives :

```
                  control      Avg_return  
2019-09-07          True            0    
2019-06-06          True            0
2019-02-19          True            0
2019-01-17          True            0
2018-12-20          True            0
2018-11-27          True            0
2018-10-12          True            0
   ...              ...            ...
```

After I load the 2 csv file

```
df2=pd.read_csv(path,parse_dates=True)
```

The print of df2 gives :

```
                  return
2010-01-01          NaN
2010-04-01     0.010920
2010-05-01    -0.004404
2010-06-01    -0.025209
2010-07-01    -0.023280
   ...            ...
```

The aim of my code is :

1. Take a date from df1
2. Subtract 6 days from the date taken in point 1.
3. Subtract 244 days from the date taken in point 1.
4. Take all the return from this two date in df2
5. Compute the mean of these return and stock it in Avg_return

I did this :

```
for i in range(0,df1_row):                   
#I go through my data df1 

    if (control.iloc[i]==True):                        
#I check if control_1 is true

      date_1=df1.index[i]-pd.to_timedelta(6, unit='d')    
# I remove 6 days from my date

      date_2=df1.index[i]-pd.to_timedelta(244, unit='d')  
# I remove 244 days from my date

      df1.loc[i,"Average_return"] = df2[[date_1:date_2],["return"]].mean()

# I want to make the mean of the return between my date-6 days and my date-244 days
```

Unfortunately it gives me this error :

```
df1.loc[i,"Average_return"] = df2[[date1:date2],["return"]].mean()
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is someone able to help me? :)

Comment: You're running into 2 potential issues here: 1. your date may or may not be your index, 2. the bit where you're using "return" doesn't make sense. I haven't tested this, but try: mask = (df['date_column'] > date1) & (df['date_column'] <= date2), then new line and
df.loc(mask).mean(). Note that, in the above, the date column would need to be renamed: date_column

Comment: did you try `df2.loc[date1:date2, 'return'].mean()`

Comment: @mjspier Yes, it doesn't work. I still have the same error

Comment: @HaydenEastwood for sure the date are the index, I forgot to put it above but yes they are. Concerning the second point, I unfortunately don't understand...

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach without looping over all rows:

```
# make sure your index is a datetime index
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)    

df1['date_1'] = df1.index - pd.to_timedelta(6, unit='d') 
df1['date_2'] = df1.index  - pd.to_timedelta(244, unit='d') 

df1['Average_return'] = df1.apply(lambda r: df2.loc[r['date_1']: r['date_2'], 'return'].mean(), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Unfortunately it gives me an error : `TypeError: cannot perform __sub__ with this index type: Index`

Comment: I guess your df1 index is not a datetime index then you can convert it like this first `df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)`

Answer (score 0):

The following looks a bit ugly, but I think it works :)

Dummy df's:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    

cols = ['date', 'control', 'Avg_return']
data = [
    [pd.to_datetime('2019-09-07'), True, 0], 
    [pd.to_datetime('2019-06-06'), True, 0]
]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

cols2 = ['date', 'return']
data2 = [
    [pd.to_datetime('2010-01-01'), np.nan], 
    [pd.to_datetime('2010-04-01'), 0.010920], 
    [pd.to_datetime('2019-09-01'), 1]
]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=cols2)
```

Drafted solution:

```
df1['date_minus_6'] = df1['date'] - dt.timedelta(days=6)
df1['date_minus_244'] = df1['date'] - dt.timedelta(days=244)

for i in range(0, df1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0, df2.shape[0]):
        if df2['date'].iloc[j] == df1['date_minus_6'].iloc[i]:
               df1['Avg_return'].iloc[i] = (
                   df1['Avg_return'].iloc[i] + df2['return'].iloc[j]
               ).mean()
        elif df2['date'].iloc[j] == df1['date_minus_244'].iloc[i]:
               df1['Avg_return'].iloc[i] = (
                   df1['Avg_return'].iloc[i] + df2['return'].iloc[j]
               ).mean()
```

Output:

```
    date    control Avg_return  date_minus_6    date_minus_244
0   2019-09-07  True    1.0 2019-09-01  2019-01-06
1   2019-06-06  True    0.0 2019-05-31  2018-10-05
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.read_csv('dsf1.csv',parse_dates=True)
df2=pd.read_csv('dsf2.csv',parse_dates=True)

df1.columns = ['date', 'control', 'return']
df2.columns = ['date', 'return']

df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
for i in range(0, df1.shape[0]):
    if df1['control'][i] == True:
        date_1 = df1['date'][0] - pd.to_timedelta(6, unit='d')
        date_2 = df2['date'][0] - pd.to_timedelta(244, unit='d')
        #I'm not sure if average_return has the correct condition, but adjust as you see fit
        df1.loc[i, 'average_return'] = (df1[df1['date'] > date_1]['return'] -  df2[df2['date'] > date_2]['return']).mean()
print df1
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but every data in average_return is Nan

Comment: Hi Stefan - I don't have the original data to hand so I can't test what it's doing. If you provide snippets of raw data that you are reading in I will be able to problem solve.